# Chrome manifest 2

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

After adding the line "manifest_version": 2, does not work jquery.rss.js, error:
Uncaught RefferenceError: $ is not defined.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="loader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rss.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="menu">
        <span><img src="images/home.png" id="url_get_home" title="Main"/></span>
        <span><img src="images/update.png" id="url_get_reload" title="Update"/></span>
        <span><img src="images/close.png" id="url_get_close" title="Close"/></span>
    </span>
    <div id="loader">
    <img src="images/plugin.png" />
    <br /><br />
    <script>
      jQuery(function($) {
        $("#rss_feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/..../Vzse", {
          limit: 5,
          effect: 'slideFastSynced'
        })
      })
    </script>
    <div id="rss_feeds"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with the code below, if you bear it in another *.js file is not a function does not work and is not called.

```
<script>
     jQuery(function($) {
            $("#rss_feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/..../Vzse", {
              limit: 5,
              effect: 'slideFastSynced'
            })
          })
        </script>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "scripts": [ "jquery.js", "popup.js", "jquery.rss.js", "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ]
   },
   "icons": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
   },
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "popup.html" ],
  "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_locale": "en",
    "default_title": "...",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }

}
```

Help solve the problem?

Comment: Also, are you including two jQuery files (`jquery.js` and `jquery-1.6.4.min.js`)?

Comment: The problem with the code jQuery(function($) ... if you remove this code in another file js it will not work because rss it reads from the file jquery.rss.js, I can move this code into jquery.js but then he does not work rss, Please show me how to do?

Comment: If you take out the inline script entirely, do you get any errors? If you move the inline script into a new file, `use_rss.js`, and reference that file with a script tag in the *exact same place* where the inline script is now, do you get any errors?

Comment: I moved the code to a file jquery.js the file does not work jquery.rss.js :

Comment: at end of file error })(jQuery)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include to exact contents of `popup.html` and the new script file you created to contain your inline script?

Comment: http://s18.postimage.org/9ymw9eyrr/Untitled_2.png

Comment: Also, *please* don't name you new file `jquery.js`. It doesn't affect the *functionality* of your code, but it does impact its *readability* -- when I see `jquery.js`, I assume it refers to a copy of the jQuery library, not a script that happens to use jQuery.

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
        $("#rss_feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/../Vzse", {
          limit: 5,
          effect: 'slideFastSynced'
        })
      })
   
 $('#url_get_home').live('click',function(){
    getHome();
    });
 
 $('#url_get_reload').live('click',function(){
    window.location.reload( true );
    });
 
 $('#url_get_close').live('click',function(){
    closePopup();
    });

Comment: I moved the function in the file and will not work anyway.

Comment: i use this script http://dawanda.github.com/jquery-rss/

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from including this in the manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "jquery.js", "popup.js", "jquery.rss.js", "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ]
 },
```

This is instructing Chrome to create a background page and run the listed scripts in order. As `jquery.rss.js` is listed before `jquery-1.6.4.min.js`, it finds `$` is not defined when it runs.

But anyway you should remove these lines altogether because you don't want a background page, you are defining a popup.

You will also need to move the inline script to a separate file, as already stated in the comments.

Comment: the problem is that the script does not work ----> http://dawanda.github.com/jquery-rss/ If I remove a row from popup.html: <script>
     jQuery(function($) {
            $("#rss_feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/..../Vzse", {
              limit: 5,
              effect: 'slideFastSynced'
            })
          })
        </script> and add a line to "manifest_version": 2, jquery-rss DOES NOT WORK)

Comment: @user1603578 Remove `jquery-1.6.4-min.js` from the end. There's **absolutely no need** to include jQuery twice. In fact, when you load a new jQuery file, any previously added plugins become invisible until `$.noConflict(true);` is used.